# Quit Contract (Industrial Placement)

Tags: contracts, united-kingdom, student, replacement

I am student, and I have successfully started a placement year job (working in a company as part of my degree).

After 10 days of working, I have observe that what the company is working with is not ideal and will not help me to improve, or to use the reference of 1 year experience to the field I would like.

I would like to ask, a general question, and speaking for UK policies, if it is possible to leave your placement without any affect or if by signing the contract, you have to stay there.

Comment: Have you considered that after 10 days you might be unqualified to state whether this job won't help you. (You haven't mentioned specifics so we don't know).

Answer (score 4):

**We cannot give legal advice. You should consult your union rep, or the student union at your university for specific matters of law and policy for your situation.**

You should bring your contract but also any agreement your university has with you about your placement. If you have any assurances in writing about what your employer has agreed to provide that they are not providing that will be useful.

Up to one month, [gov.uk](https://www.gov.uk/handing-in-your-notice-resigning-leaving-job) says you do not need to give notice to quit a job unless your contract says so, after which you need to give one week's notice. Your employer might argue that the wording of the contract implies otherwise, you will need a union rep or solicitor to advise on this.

However, as this is a work placement as part of a degree, you may have made an agreement with your university about this. If you quit without finding an approved alternative placement, you may not be able to complete your degree. Your student union will probably be able to advise about who in the university you can talk to about this. At this point, arranging a better placement may not be possible and you could be better off trying to make the most of what you have.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I think I agree with evreything you said. The only think is that University talked us that if you failed for any reason to complete your placement, you will lose the ability to write on your degree that you did a placement and your degree will be a regular one, so I don't think this will be the case hopefully.

Comment: We can't advise you on your university's policies either. Talk to them about the situation.

Answer (score -1):

In all honesty, I would consult an employment law attorney in your country, or do a research on the UK employment laws. Speaking from the point of law in the U.S., a majority of employment contracts in the private sector are deemed what we call at-will, meaning either the employee or the employer can terminate the contract at any time without reason. You may want to look and see if your area has similar laws.

Comment: This is almost never the case in Europe... In the OPs case, as it's been less than a month it _might_ be.